# sqldeveloper export tool ignores filter by schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to export an Oracle schema to an .sql file. It has no tables, but it has some custom types and packages.

During the steps "specify objects" and "specify data" I click "More" and select the schema to export. During the step "specify objects" I also click "Lookup" and move all objects from the left panel to the right panel. As there's no tables, I cannot do the same on the "specify data" step.

When I start exporting the tool exports the tables owned by the current user anyways. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the Cart feature?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" >> Did you try to connect as user whose objects you're trying to export?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to click "More" or "Lookup". On the right side, there shows "All" by default, which means all objects will be exported. The image is illustrated as below.

[image]

Comment: That dropdown is for object types.

Comment: Have you ever tried the solution? I have tested it , the result contains only DDL as I expected.

Comment: what did you select there?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nothing. The only things I did is to uncheck "Export Data", then I followed "Next".